# PyQt5. Установка зависимости размера виджета от размера окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, tkinter

У меня есть виджет PyQt5, например кнопка. Как сделать, чтобы при изменении размера окна это кнопка тоже меняла свои размеры. 
В tkinter это выглядит так: 
`widget.pack(fill = BOTH)`

Comment: Поместить эту кнопку в какой-либо layout, который в свою очередь установить в родительский виджет

Comment: покажите пример, который у вас написан на `PyQt5`